# Is there any way to parametrize Contains() function in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is there any way in tableau to give multiple value inside Contains() function or any other function in tableau.

Example:  We have 1300 Studies with name starting from 08815,34678,SHP-HT-05, etc. Can I search for multiple studies and get values of matched studies.

Currently, I can do it for one study but i am unable to do for multiple studies.

Contain([Studyid],"088") will give me study 08815.

but i want both 08815 and 34678 Is, there any way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

One (somewhat klunky) approach is to define a handful of parameters, say up to 3. Then write your filtering calculated field to consider all three. Say define a calculated field called **Matching Study Id** as

```
([Param 1] <> “” and Contains[Studyid], [Param 1])) or
([Param 2] <> “” and Contains[Studyid], [Param 2])) or
([Param 3] <> “” and Contains[Studyid], [Param 3]))
```

Then put **Matching Study Id** on the filter shelf (filtering to true)

This will let the user enter up to three literal strings, and will match all study ids that contain any of the search strings somewhere within the StudyId.

Another approach is to use a wildcard filter on StudyId.

Or you could use a single parameter and the REGEX related functions to find matches

Comment: It will work if we know how many known values we need to  pass. Let say we need to pass 50 parameters. I can't it ([Param 1] <> “” and Contains[Studyid], [Param 1])) this expression 50 times. Is there any way where I can pass List instead of 50 parameters?

Comment: Hi Alex, In short I want to pass dynamic values.

Comment: You’re right that this technique does not scale beyond a few parameters. You could use a single parameter to specify a regular expression which could scale up further — but would be awkward for a list of 50 items. Another option is to have the user provide their list of names in a file or table that Tableau uses as a data source, and then use cross datasource filters or . If that doesn’t fit your needs, use the JavaScript API or write an extension

Comment: Sets and set actions are another useful feature in Tableau that can be used in some cases where you would like a multi-valued parameter. But they will require that you have some data source (even a simple one) with a list of possible values that the user can select to be in the set of interest.